# Being forced to pass an object itself when calling class methods - am I doing it wrong?

Tags: python, class

If I made some sort of function like this:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = 0

    def count(self) -> int:
        self._count += 1
        return self._count

    def reset(self) -> None:
        self._count = 0
```

and put this in the python shell:

```
>>> s = Counter
>>> s.count()
```

I end up with this:

> TypeError: count() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Am I doing something wrong? I don't understand why I would have to pass an object itself for its own method. I thought that it is automatically passed because I access the method using the period. At least this is how (I remember, perhaps incorrectly) it being in C++ so it doesn't make sense to me that this would this way in python. Am I doing something wrong?

Basically, why do I need to pass it s.count(s) rather than just do s.count(). Shouldn't self already initialize to the variable before the period?

Comment: Use `()` to create an instance: `s = Counter()`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, why leave an answer as a comment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
s = Counter
```

This doesn't create an instance of the `Counter` class.  It assigns the `Counter` class to the variable `s`.  This means that you're trying to call an instance method on the class itself in the second line.

If you want to create an instance of the `Counter` class, you should write:

```
s = Counter()
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. Is my mistake similar to doing s = int?

Comment: Pretty much, although it's not a syntax error as it would be in C++ because classes are first-class objects in Python, which means you can assign them to variables and pass them around etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with your code:

1) In your method definitions in your class you use invalid syntax with `def count(self) -> int:` and `def reset(self) -> None:` which you'll notice I modified to remove the `->` and `int`/`None`.

2) Instantiating [Class Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) should use function notation, so `s = Counter()` instead of `s = Counter`.

Both of these problems have been fixed in the code below:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = 0

    def count(self):
        self._count += 1
        return self._count

    def reset(self):
        self._count = 0

s = Counter()
print s.count()
```